# Why values pushed to the array is not available, even though the array is declared as globally accessable?

Tags: jquery, backend

i have declared an array globally so that i can modify that inside a function. but after i try and modify the array. the array is showing showing any data and the array is alwayes becomes 0.

this is where the function is been callled from:

```
var vehicleTypesArr = []; //globally accessable.

function loadVehicleTypes(data) {
            if (data != null) {
                var res = data.VehicleTypes;
                if (res != '' && res != null) {
                    $.each(res, function () {
                        if (res.GroupName === 'ConEnhTyp_Vehicle')
                            vehicleTypesArr.push(this);
                           //console() : if i put a console here, the result will the data with specific groupName and prints until the loop is ended with the data.
                    });
                }
            }
            console.log(JSON.stringify(vehicleTypesArr)); // console 1 : result = 0
            resetVehicleTypes(); //here i call 2nd code snippet
};
```

This is the 2nd code snippet:

```
function resetVehicleTypes() {
  alert("1");
  if (vehicleTypesArr.length > 0) {
  alert("2");
    $.each(vehicleTypesArr, function (val) {
      val.prop('checked', false); 
  });
  alert("1");
  }
  alert("Finished");
}
```

the code enters the function and alerts the 1, and then goes staright to the finished alert.

I tried,

on the console() : i  put a console and the result was the data with specific groupName and prints until the loop is ended with the data.

but in the console 1 the array is empty. i tried changing length condition and its not working.

still has no supprt.

Comment: Is `this` a object? Might have a problem with object prototype. Could try `Object.assign({}, this)` which will make a level 1 deep copy of object. For multi level can always `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` or write a copy function.

Comment: Yes, this is an object with 2 arrays inside. both have different groupName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code does work in all(that are shown) possible ways a object can be pushed into array.
It looks like the issue is with your if statement in each loop. I recommend always using `{}` braces. Guessing the condition `res.GroupName === 'ConEnhTyp_Vehicle'` is never true...

```js
const result1 = document.getElementById('result1');

var vehicleTypesArr = []; //globally accessable.
const some_data = {
  VehicleTypes: [{
      GroupName: 'name 1'
    },
    {
      GroupName: 'name 2'
    }
  ]
};

loadVehicleTypes(some_data);

function loadVehicleTypes(data) {
  if (data != null) {
    var res = data.VehicleTypes;
    if (res != '' && res != null) {
      // alternative to for loops
      //vehicleTypesArr = res.filter(el => el.GroupName === 'ConEnhTyp_Vehicle');
    
      $.each(res, function() {
        // edit: should be this.GroupName instead of res.GroupName
        //if (res.GroupName === 'ConEnhTyp_Vehicle') // not needed for test
        vehicleTypesArr.push(this); // works
        vehicleTypesArr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this))); // works
        vehicleTypesArr.push(Object.assign({}, this)); // works
        vehicleTypesArr.push({ ...this
        }); // works
      });

      /*
      for (const el of res) {
        vehicleTypesArr.push(el); // works
        vehicleTypesArr.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(el))); // works
        vehicleTypesArr.push(Object.assign({}, el)); // works
        vehicleTypesArr.push({ ...el
        }); // works
      }
      */
    }
  }

  result1.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(vehicleTypesArr);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result1">test</div>
```

Edit:
Looking back at it. The if statement is checking `res.GroupName` when it should be checking `this.GroupName`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `this.vehicleTypesArr` instead of just `vehicleTypesArr` within your functions

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and that works.